# Elasticsearch: find document doesn't have intersecting nested items

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have a document with nested collection and the goal is to find that ones which don't have any inner items intersecting particular period considering also an item's status.

inb4 I've found at least two SO items that didn't help me (probably I'm noob):
[ElasticSearch - find all documents whose nested documents do not intersect with date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714760/elasticsearch-find-all-documents-whose-nested-documents-do-not-intersect-with) 
and 
[Elasticsearch inverse range overlap query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622781/elasticsearch-inverse-range-overlap-query)

So, my document, let's say, simple (I'll paste a JSON definition, just for simplicity. all mappings are fine, trust me ;) ):

```json
{
  "maintenances": [ // <-- this is nested collection
  {
    "start": "date/time",
    "end": "date/time",
    "status": boolean
  } ]
}
```

What I need is to write a query for documents that don't have any active (`status = true`) maintenance items intersecting some period (`from` and `to` for instance).

I started from simple expression:

```json
must_not { nested { exists { field: maintenances } } }
or
must_not { nested { must [
  { maintenances.start <= to },
  { maintenances.end >= from },
  { status = true }
] } }
```

That returned me any document from test entries.
Remembering that nested query will return outer document in case if **any** document will match expression I decided to make a query complex, something like:

```json
maintenances not exists
or
(
  any maintenance within range is not active
  and
  any maintenance outside range is active
)
```

But it became clear (not very fast unfortunately) that this query doesn't work for sorts of edge-cases: like all nested maintenance items are inactive, or all maintenance are outside requested bounds.

Currently I'm not sure, but I assume that query should contain as many **or**-d items as many edge-cases are? Like:

```json
maintenances not exists
or
(
  any maintenance within range is not active
  and
  any maintenance outside range
)
or
(
  any maintenance within range is not active
  and
  no maintenance outside range
)
or
(
  no maintenance within range
  and
  any maintenance outside range
)
or
OVER9000 of them
```

Does anyone know simplest way to query Elastic for my case?

Answer (score 0):

> all mappings are fine, trust me

Suddenly (no actually) this was an issue. Absence of mapping for `status` prevented from data being filtered correctly.